# Algorithm writing style not correct as per desired

Tags: algorithms

[image]

This is the algorithm I want to write down in latex. But after write down some code it cannot give me desire output.

My code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The GraphSlam Algorithm for the Full SLAM Problem with known Correspondence}\label{algo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State\textbf{{Algorithm GraphSLAM\textunderscore known\textunderscore
    correspondence}}
\State $\mu_{0:t}$ = GraphSLAM\textunderscore initialize(u_{1:t})
\State repeat
\State $\Omega$,$\xi$ = GraphSLAM\textunderscore linearize(u_{1:t},z_{1:t},c_{1:t},$\mu_{0:t}$)
\State $\bar\Omega$,$\bar\xi$ = GraphSLAM\textunderscore reduce($\Omega$,$\xi$)
\State $\mu$,$\Sigma_{0:t}$ = GraphSLAM\textunderscore solve($\bar\Omega$,$\bar\xi$,$\Omega$,$\xi$)
\State until convergence
\State return $\mu$

    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

I get this output

[image]

How will I get the desired output?

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick mock-up that matches your layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{algorithm}[2][htbp]
  {\begin{table}[#1]
     \caption{#2}%
     \setcounter{algline}{0}% Reset algorithm line counter
     \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
     \itshape
     \begin{tabular}{| p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth} |}
       \hline
  }
  {    \\
       \hline
     \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
  }

\newcounter{algline}
\newlength{\algnummargin}
\setlength{\algnummargin}{2em}
\newcommand{\algline}{%
  \refstepcounter{algline}%
  \makebox[\algnummargin][l]{\textup{\small\thealgline:}}%
}
\newcommand{\textbfup}[1]{\textbf{\textup{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}{The GraphSLAM Algorithm for the Full SLAM Problem with Known Correspondence}
  \algline \textbfup{Algorithm GraphSLAM\_known\_correspondence($u_1$, $z_1$, $c_1$):} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  \algline $\mu_0 = \textbfup{GraphSLAM\_initialize($u_1$)}$ \\
  \algline repeat \\
  \algline \quad $\Omega, \xi = \textbfup{GraphSLAM\_linearize($u_1$, $z_1$, $c_1$, $\mu_1$)}$ \\
  \algline \quad $\bar{\Omega}, \bar{\xi} = \textbfup{GraphSLAM\_reduce($\Omega$, $\xi$)}$ \\
  \algline \quad $\mu, \Sigma_0 = \textbfup{GraphSLAM\_solve($\bar{\Omega}$, $\bar{\xi}$, $\Omega$, $\xi$)}$ \\
  \algline until convergence \\
  \algline return $\mu$
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The algorithm caption is set as the mandatory argument for the `algorithm` environment.